# alternative and compatibale injectors

Tags: ford, fuel-injectors

A ford focus MK2 owner has been advised to replace the fuel injectors but the brand new OEM injectors are rare and expensive, so we are looking for compatible injectors that are used for another brand like PSA instead of Ford which could possibly be found easier and cheaper.

The engine is 1.8 TDCI and the injectors are Siemens 5ws40086 ( according to my research ) and i have found this [cross reference from Siemens](http://www.dizeluserviss.lv/_technical-data/siemens/cross-siemens-vdo-common-rail.pdf) but couldn't understand how to make use of it.

Comment: I'm seeing as how the injectors you are looking for are not what I'd call cheap (ie: €235,00 Excluded VAT). Have you thought about getting the injectors you have already refurbished? I think the injectors you are looking for off of the chart are VDO PN: A2C59511610  - In the chart, it's the column marked "ordernumber" and corresponds to the part number you are showing above. I used this to get the price I'm showing. You could order them off of eBay for about $91/ea ... a lot cheaper, but still not what I'd call affordable.

Comment: @Paulster2 we have tried refurbishing them  but it led to the worst results, the car didn't start for days and the repair shop kept messing with them till it started worst than before (shaking and won't start if the engine get hot ) . Ordering from eBay is impossible here and could turn into a mess due to laws and taxes here . The reason I'm looking for a PSA injector is because these brands are very common here and could be found new or refurbished easily, thanks for the help.

Comment: The repairshop didn't have the proper tools or parameters for those injectors .could try another one but the car owner wants to just skip this and get new ones as these engines are known by this failure.